# Inserting a link from a CSV

Tags: php, csv

This codes pulls data from a CSV file and displays them as a table

```
<?php
                $lines = file('graphdata/Dimensions.csv');      

                foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
                    if($lineNum == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    print "         <tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";

                    $tokens = str_getcsv($line);
                    print "<td style=\"width: 200px;\">" . trim($tokens[0])  "</td>";           
                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</td>";  
                    print "</script>\n";
                }
            ?>
```

The first column is actually an hyperlinked text while the link itself may appear as a cell in the relevant row in the CSV

Is there away to make the text in the first column to appear as hyperlink?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you downvoted, does it not make text a hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the line to:

```
   print "<td style=\"width: 200px;\"><a href=\"" . trim($tokens[0]) . "\">" . trim($tokens[0])  "</a></td>";
```

The general syntax for anchor tag is:

```
<a href="link_address">Visible text</a>
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: @user3387046 Could you accept this as answer please, if it worked for you!!

Answer (score 1):

General syntax:

```
echo '<a href="' . $linktTarget . '">' . $linkName . '</a>';
```

More clear way to do it is just to combain '' and "": 
 
 edit: Oh you wanted to whole `<td></td>`, be the linke, here you go:

```
              <?php
                    $lines = file('graphdata/Dimensions.csv');      

                    foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
                        if($lineNum == 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        print '<tr id="tr' . $lineNum . '">';

                        $tokens = str_getcsv($line);
                        print '<td style="width: 200px;"><a href="' . trim($tokens[0]) . '">' . trim($tokens[0]) . '</a></td>';           
                        print '<td style="width: 100px;">' . trim($tokens[1]) . '</td>';  
                        print '</script><br />';
                    }
                ?>
```

Also what for is:

```
print '</script><br />';
```

at the end?

I have found that the previous way wasn't working in anything other than IE, simplest way to do it across all browsers, is to just add below to your css file:

```
CSS code:

td a{width:100%;display:block;}
```